# Problem while solving this combinatorial geometry puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

I'm a math olympiad trainee and received this problem during one of my practice tests. I have seen such problems before but always struggle to solve them. Any tips / solutions to this would be greatly appreciated.

Q) Gerrard drew 100 lines on the plane, with no three lines passing through the same point. These lines divide up the plane in various parts, and some of those parts are triangle shaped. Gerrard claims that he can draw another line that does not pass through any of the existing intersection points, and it intersects atleast 60 triangle shaped parts. Show that Gerrard's claim cannot be true.

Comment: A friend sent this same problem to me with Gerard replaced by a different name. He claims it’s from India MOP training.

Comment: Does not the fact that there 60 triangles intersected mean that there are at least 121 lines drawn?

Comment: How can we be sure of that @Moti

Comment: Does he have a solution for it @TheBestMagician

Comment: you can use induction to prove it. I assumed there are not parallel lines. So, you must assume some parallel lines. From these two you may be able to have the proof.

Comment: I'm actually not well versed with induction techniques so if you have a solution that I can look at and learn that would be great. @Moti

Comment: You can first prove that there are no two triangle parts with a common side, using the fact that no three lines passes through the same point. This implies that for each triangle part intersected by the claimed line, the claimed line intersects two of the 100 lines, all of them distinct.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. How do I proceed @Guyslain

Comment: For the first part? Take a triangle and one of its edge. What can you tell about the shape opposite of the triangle for this side (what are the lines, and how many, bordering it)?

Comment: No I got the first part. It's like how do I proceed forward in the proof @Guyslain

Comment: Like how do I get to the 60 triangle shaped parts ?

Comment: For each triangular parts intersected by Gerrard's line, we can define two intersection points (where his line intersects the triangle). Because no two triangles intersects, all these points are distinct. Finally all these points are on distinct lines among the 100 lines (as two different lines intersect in at most one point).

Comment: Makes sense. And next ? @Guyslain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

1. Let us call a *vertex* a point on the plane where 2 lines intersect, and let us call an *edge* $e$ a line segment where each endpoint of $e$ is a vertex. Then the condition that no 3 lines intersect at a single point gives the condition that each edge $e$ is in at most $1$ triangle.
2. The condition that two lines intersect at at most $1$ point gives the condition that the $101$st line $L$ intersects at most $100$ edges.
3. If $L$ intersects a triangle, then $L$ intersepts $2$ edges of the triangle.

So the number of triangles that $L$ can intersept, is  [from 1 and 3 above], the number of edges $L$ intersepts, divided by $2$. By 2 above, this is at most $50$.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It is correct

Comment: Some users, when they feel that a question doesn't meet site standards, will downvote answers, even correct answers, to discourage other users from answering substandard questions, Mike.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson yes I can see if someone had asked something trivial, but I thought this was a good question. It was satisfying for me when I figured it out!

Comment: What some users object to is not the level of difficulty of the question, but the level of effort the poster has put into it. Go to the meta site, find the post about *Enforcement of Quality Standards*.

Comment: I agree with the fact that anonymous downvotes is not a good thing on this site. **But** it is true when you see the kind of comments the OP has made that he asks for a solution at any price without personal involvement.